# useReducer not updating proper dispatch value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Beginner in reactjs and have tried everything I could. The 'contacts' is always undefined.
Note that i've removed some unrelated code and have only pasted relevant code here.

Thanks in advance

```
const initialState = {
        contacts: ["test@test.com"],
        loggedInUser: null,
        isChatPage: true
    }

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(chatReducer, initialState);  

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.contacts);
}, [state]);

const setContacts = (contactList) => {
        console.log(contactList);
    
        dispatch({
            type: SET_CONTACT_LIST,
            payoad: contactList
        })
    }
```

the userReducer function is

```
const chatReducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    console.log(state);
    switch(action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_CHAT:
            return {
                ...state,
                isChatPage: action.payload
            }

        case SET_LOGGED_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loggedInUser: action.payload
            }

        case SET_CONTACT_LIST:
            return {
                ...state,
                contacts: action.payload
            }
    }
}
```

And the setContact is called from another file as below:

```
 const context = useContext(ChatContext);

    const updateRealTimeUsers = () => {
        db.collection("users")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            var users = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                users.push(doc.data().email);
            });
            console.log("Current users: ", users);
            context.setContacts(users);
            
        });
    
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updateRealTimeUsers();
        // console.log(contacts);
        
    }, []);
```

And the logging from chatReducer is below:

```
{type: "SET_CONTACT_LIST", payoad: Array(3)}
payoad: (3) ["dummy@gmail.com", "testasdasd@gmail.com", "test123@gmail.com"]
type: "SET_CONTACT_LIST"
[[Prototype]]: Object
chat-reducer.js:5 
{messages: Array(13), chats: Array(12), users: Array(7), contacts: null, contactsDummy: Array(1), …}
chats: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
contacts: null
isChatPage: true
loggedInUser: {email: "test123@gmail.com", uid: "0aic691KY4ZmJDXv3T6mji9qZnO2"}
messages: (13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
test: (3) [1, 2, 3]
user: {}
users: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typing mistake in `setContacts`. You write `payoad` instead of `payload`!

```
const setContacts = (contactList) => {
        console.log(contactList);
    
        dispatch({
            type: SET_CONTACT_LIST,
            payoad: contactList
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Such a trivial mistake took up so much time!